# css border-top issue,cant added to one line

Tags: css

```
  Im added   `li { border-top:1px solid #80bee3;}` 

 .days li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 13.6%;border-top:1px solid #80bee3;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 8px;
font-size:12px;
color: #777;
```

}

but this border displayed

1           2        3        4           5         6        7           8

-----     ----      ----     ----        ----     ----      ----        ----
its is  separate line  not only one border, How to take that only one border 
(look my attached image )

How to fix that issue,
Thanks 
[image]

```
 <ion-list>
          <ul class="days list">
            <li><ion-item>1</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>2 <div class="book-risk"></div></ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>3</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>4</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>5<div class="book-risk"></div></ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>6</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>7</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>8</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>9</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item><div class="active">1</div>10</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>11</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>12</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>13<div class="book-event"></div></ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>14</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>15</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>16</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>17</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>18</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>19</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>20</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>21</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>22</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>23</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>24</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>25</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>26</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>27</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>28</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>29</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>30</ion-item></li>
            <li><ion-item>31</ion-item></li>
          </ul>


        </ion-list>
```

Comment: can you add your complete css

Comment: I'm assuming `<li>`'s are set to `display: inline-block`? If so, you need to set the font-size on the UL to 0 and then reset it to whatever it should be on the LIs. The reason is that inline-blocks preserve whitespace between them, and since all your LIs are on new lines, they all have a space between. You could also fix it by putting all your LIs on the same line in your code, no spaces between them.

Comment: @Geeky Sir, Im updated my question

Comment: @delinear Sir `display: inline-block;` is not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you need to set the font of the Ul to 0 and then reset it on the LIs, like so:

```
.days {
  font-size: 0;
}
.days li {
  font-size:12px;
}
```

This should remove the white-space between the LIs.

Comment: Sir ,Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `float:left;` to `li` tag. And `padding: 0;` is also required if additional `padding` is applied from parent elements.

Comment: Sir ,Thanks for your solution